# The best way to skip a line in html?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I've read and visited a lot of websites, but none  of them have provided me with a simple solution. What i want to know is what's the best way to add/skip a line in html? What I mostly use is two `<br />` tags, but I know that there is a simpler solution to the problem. Is there a way to skip a line, using css, instead of doing this:

```
<p>Hello. <br /><br />This is a test</p>
```

Comment: what bout css: margin-bottom ?

Comment: Use <pre> tags. Input text as you want to show on page inside <pre> tags

Comment: @ItayB magin-bottom? I don't think that's a clean and proper way of doing it.

Comment: @AksheyBhat I agree `<pre>` is definitevely something you need if you text contains some line breaks.

Comment: @Lebone There are a lot of ways to achieve your goal. You ask for css solution, one of the css solution is the one I've suggested..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could simply use 2 separate paragraph (`<p>`) tags. For example:

```
<p>Hello.</p>
<p>This is a test</p>
```

Here's a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DPcgYrfVo09yFCRN8XrB?p=preview).

Comment: Easy and simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Semantically, it depends on your purpose. Do whatever's best in the situation. Some examples.

1. If you literally need to skip a line, that is, have a empty line with nothing on it in your text, then by all means use two `<br>` elements.

   ```html
   This is one line of text<br>
   This is also one line of text<br>
   The next line happens to be empty<br>
   <br>
   And here is another line, not empty<br>
   ```

   And so on.
2. However, if you want to create some blank space between two blocks of prose, then the two blocks should be paragraphs, as mentioned in the other answers.
3. And if the first part is a bunch of individual lines, but the second part is a piece of prose, only the second part needs to be a paragraph. No need to enclose the first part in `<p>` tags as well. Example:

   ```html
   Add the water to the recipe<br>
   Add the salt<br>

   <p>Note: stir thoroughly!</p>
   ```
4. If your intention is to actually *separate* two lines of text, to signify they don't belong together, you can use a `<hr>`. Make it invisible if you want.

   ```html
   This is some text
   <hr style="opacity:0">
   This is some unrelated text
   ```
5. If the next line happens to be an introduction to the later half of the text, change it into a `<h4>` (that is, a header at whatever level you require here).

   ```html
   The last line of the previous section
   <h4>Introduction</h4>
   The fist line of the next section
   ```

   This works because headers also have margins built in.
6. Lastly, if you have an existing piece of html with your two blocks of text already in two HTML elements, you don't necessarily have to change the markup; all you need to do is set top and bottom margins for those elements in the CSS.
   Suppose they are in `<section>`s:

   ```html
   <style>
     section {margin:1em 0}
   </style>
   ...
   ... The last line of the previous section</section>
   <section>The fist line of the next section ...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can surround the 'Hello' with div and add css of maring-bottom for example:

```
<p>
    <div style='margin-bottom: 40px;'>Hello.</div>
    This is a test
</p>
```

Comment: Browsers may handle that, but a `<div>` inside a [`<p>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) element is not valid. Only [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) is valid.

Comment: Browsers won't "handle" that; they all close the `<p>` before the `<div>` starts.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using br tag is always a bad idea. Try using paragraphs, css padding, css margin, hr. Try avoiding br because it's not [semantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) and using the proper tag in your site "helps the search" engines to "understand your site"

Answer (score 0):

`<p>Hello.  <br /> &nbsp; <br> This is a test</p>`

Comment: If you absolutely want to use <br /> tag.

Comment: How is this better than the OP's own example?

Answer (score 0):

Using block level elements would help. for example, p is a block level element which would give the line break.

so you can have the text in two paragraphs. and have the margin/padding set to the paragraph

using `<br>` is a bad approach.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this where you want the blank space:

```
    &nbsp;
```

If you want multiple blank spaces, then repeat the code successively like this:

```
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
```

etc.